# Creating a PPA for my app

Tags: apt, ppa

Im stumped. i have a app and its being packaged into .deb files, so i wanted to create a ppa... my goals were pretty simple:

make the ppa available

host it on github with actions or whatever

After some research and 4 hours later, idk what to do... reperpo and all of those tools eighter dont work or are confusing af, and all of the guides are outdate... Everything i tried didnt work, or fell when trying to do apt update... (Signing error)

Does anyone have a nice quick and clear guide? THX!

Comment: Official guides are not outdated. It is unclear what you want and what you did. You can't upload a deb to a PPA. You can't host it on github, etc.

Comment: What Ubuntu *official* guide is out-of-date?   Anytime a change is made, they are amended.  I've been watching a new (*future dev*) learn to package & has had little trouble understanding the official packaging guides; yes there are loads of questions on IRC - but we all need that when *learning*. Either way no changes to documentation have been required in the past 28 days from instruction I've witnessed,

Comment: @guiverc they arent rly out of date, but they use strange tools, which for me didnt work and would be a pain to automete...

Comment: @Pilot6 very helpful, thx... #sarcasm

Comment: Launchpad is not a PPA hosting service. It is a *source code* hosting service that pre-dates github and includes a free package-building/hosting feature (called PPA). To host a PPA, you *must* use Launchpad. To use Launchpad, you *must* keep your code there and build it using their tools (it's a security feature). Launchpad speaks git, and has been compatible with most git-based tools for over a decade. Some projects sync their code from github/lab to Launchpad for building. Folks who balk at the quite mild requirements of Launchpad are welcome to distribute their package elsewhere themself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This assumes you are creating the packaging. You can't just take an already-built .deb and upload it to a PPA.

reprepo is not something you need to worry about for a PPA. That is for building your own repository that you will host directly.

To create a PPA and upload to it:

1. You need an account on Launchpad. You need to have your GPG public key associated with that account.
2. Create a PPA on Launchpad under your account (or a team, if appropriate).
3. Locally (on your computer) build a signed, *source* build of the package, e.g. debuild -S -sa
4. Upload to the PPA: dput ppa:your_username/your_ppa_name
5. Repeat steps 3 and 4 as new versions of the software come out or when you need to modify the packaging.

The Ubuntu build servers will build the package. If it succeeds, they will publish it. Both of these steps can take tens of minutes to small numbers of hours. So you really need to be sure the package is building correctly locally first, before uploading it.

Comment: the problem with your version is, that lets say i want to automate it, i cant rly... so i want to avoid launchpad... (theres my idea of hosting on github pages)

Comment: @GameTec_live You can't avoid Launchpad if you want a PPA. PPA is a Launchpad feature. You can host your deb files somewhere else. But not many people will risk downloading executables from an unknown place. Launchpad guarantees that binaries match the source.